# How does ng-selected work?

Tags: angularjs

Here is a snippet. Q2 is selected as I expect.

```
<select name="quarter" ng-model="Quarter" >
    <option value="1" >Q1</option>
    <option value="2" ng-selected="Quarter=='Q1'">Q2</option>
    <option value="3">Q3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Changing `'Q1'` to `'Q2`' makes nothing as selected as I expect. Now putting `ng-selected="Quarter=='Q1'"` DOES NOT make Q1 selected until i delete `ng-selected="Quarter=='Q2"`

wtf. How is this suppose to work?

Comment: this seems to be working for me or is this not what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/xpjaD/

Comment: @Ronnie: That IS what I am trying to do. WTH. I deleted all my controller code except that assignment to Q1 and... i guess something is very wrong in the html

Comment: @Ronnie: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772672/why-does-ng-selected-not-work-with-ng-repeater

Comment: Simplest way use <b>ng-init</b><br>
[Follow this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41925114/4805527)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you put the ng-selected on the option element, your option will be selected when the ng-selected value is true. In your case, the option Q2 is selected when Quarter is equal to Q1.

If you want to select the value passed in Quarter, you must put the ng-selected on the select element :

```
<select name="quarter" ng-model="Quarter" ng-selected="Quarter"
        ng-options="Quarter for Quarter in Quarters" >
    {{Quarter}}
</select>
```

Take a look at the [select directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: Interesting but also wtf. I don't see ng-options on the api website docs.angularjs.org/api/ Also it doesnt seem to work with ng-repeater http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772672/why-does-ng-selected-not-work-with-ng-repeater

Comment: ng-options is an attribute of the select directive : [doc.angularjs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select)

Comment: Your fiddle has been flagged as unsafe due to it having an embedded iframe as the only content...!!! sketchy!

Comment: Really weird... I give a link to the official doc instead. Thanks!

Comment: it seems that it just solve the problem of choosing a default option but when default is selected the model does not updated properly.please give a solution for updating the model too

Comment: This just didn't work for me when populating options with an ng-repeat. This answer did, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31676786/498949

Answer (score 5):

```
<select ng-model="hour">
    <option ng-selected="hour == $index" ng-repeat="h in (((b=[]).length=24)&&b) track by $index" ng-bind="$index">{{h}}</option>
</select>
```

if you want a select for 24 hour, you can do this.

Answer (score 5):

like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{referenceNumber}}
    <select ng-model="referenceNumber">
            <option ng-selected="!referenceNumber">Default</option>
            <option ng-repeat="number in numbers track by $index" ng-value="number">{{number}}</option>
        </select>
  </body>
```

> "I believe one of the main reasons for ngSelected is to set default
>   values depending upon if the model is not set correctly." joshkurz commented on Mar 3, 2014

So the right way would be to rely on ng-model only in you case.
The right way to do what you are trying to do(pre select a option) is like this:

```
<select ng-model="purchase.product" name="purchase.product" class="u-full-width" ng-options="product.id as product.name for product in products"></select>
```

Reference:

1. http://plnkr.co/edit/xXq3b40nvqkjPlyCxZNG?p=preview
2. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6528

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-selected` directive takes a boolean value or an expression which leads to a true/false boolean result.

You just need to pass its value `true` to make it work or an expression which leads to `true`.

It has nothing to do with ng-model of `<select>` tag.

Following is an example of this behaviour:

```
<select name="quarter" ng-model="Quarter" >
    <option value="1" >Q1</option>
    <option value="2" ng-selected="true">Q2</option>
    <option value="3">Q3</option>
    <option value="4">Q4</option>
</select>
```

This will make option Q2 selected by default.